# Applying method to stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm learning how to use streams in Java. I have a file with some info that I want to load in some data structure, for example, a Set.

I wrote a function to parse each line.

```
private Food parseFoodLine(String line){
    String[] items = line.split("|");
    Food food = #Parsing done here. 
    return food;
}
```

But how do I put each line through that method?

```
private Set<Food> loadFood(){
    Set<Food> food = new HashSet<>();
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("myFile"))) {
        stream.forEach(parseFoodLine());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error parsing file");
    }
}
```

I understand I should do "stream.forEach(food::add)" but how do I get a food object from my file?

Comment: Aside: you might well want to use `\\|` rather than `|` as your split pattern.

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `map` the elements of your `Stream<String>` to `Food` instances (via your `parseFoodLine` method) and them use `collect` to collect them into a `Set`:

```
food = stream.map(Food::parseFoodLine).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Note that your `Food` class should override `equals` and `hashCode` properly in order for `Food` instances to be correctly stored in a `HashSet`.

Comment: more accurately to a mutable `HashSet`... i.e. `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));` but might not even matter depending on the use case of the `food` collection once it's returned to the calling method.